# What makes this program crash?

Tags: c++, crash

I have tried looking at my code but I couldn't find the problem. What did I do wrong ? Though I think that its `l=ats/(s/60)` that's causing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int ats=7,v1=12,v2=12,m1=30,m2=40,g=70,l,s;
s=abs(((v2*60+m2)-(v1*60+m1))%60);
l=ats/(s/60);
cout << l;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good opportunity to [learn how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: BTW, you can add spaces between operators, as the compiler ignores them, but they make your code more readable.

Comment: A good coding style is to declare one variable per line.  This is easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have integer division by zero in line `l=ats/(s/60);`. `s` and `60` are both integers, so when you divide `s=10`, and `60` using integer division you get `0`, and when you divide `ats` by `0` you get a crash. If you want to avoid the integer division in this case, use either:

a) `l=ats/(s/60.0);`

b) `l=ats/(static_cast<double> (s)/60);`

But note, after this change, the result would no longer be of `int` type. If you want to have an int there, you would need to cast it back to `int` again using `static_cast<int>` as follows: `l=static_cast<int> (ats/(s/60.0))`.

Answer (score 3):

You have an integer division by zero. That's undefined behaviour in C++.

`s` is *never* bigger than 59 due to the modulus.

`s / 60` will always be zero, since integer division *truncates*.

Answer (score 3):

because of the `%60`, `s` will always be an integer between 0 and 59 (inclusive). on the next line, the `s/60`  will always be < 1, and therefore truncated to `0` since it's integer division. dividing `ats` by this results in divide by 0

Answer (score 1):

`s` is integer less than 60. Integer division `(s/60)` gives `0`. So, `ats` is divided by zero.